# How to prevent Hive Create Table from splitting the column that has comma "," inside the data into two columns

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I imported MySQL table using Sqoop. Some of the column values has comma "," in them. For example, "value, ST". I want to store that value in the same column like how its in MySQL but when i create Hive table, "value" and "ST" are stored in separate column. "ST" goes into the right column.

I've tried this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal_to_delete 
(id_personal string, 
no_ktp string, 
nama string, 
nama_tanpa_gelar string, 
alamat1 string, 
kodepos string, 
id_kabupaten_alamat string, 
id_propinsi string, 
npwp string, 
tgl_update string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\",
   "quoteChar"     = ","")
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hadoop/personal_to_delete';
```

I get Null values after i run this query. How do i solve this?

Comment: can you pls try creating a simple table using hive and not mention serde properties? `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal_to_delete 
(id_personal string,..... ) stored as parquet; ` Let hive handle them internally.

Comment: Test `FIELDS ... OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using csv after the sqoop import? Also, sqoop can be used with hcatalog to create tables for you

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the seperator character used for separating the fields also appears in the values itself. This makes it difficult for the create table command to correctly work. You need either

- to escape this character within the fields or
- use a quote Character to enclose the fields or
- use a different field seperator which does not appear in the fields itself
  to make the file "easy understandable" for the import process.

I myself would probably take one of this 2 options:

1. As suggested by OneCricketeer: Let sqoop directly import to a hive table. Here seems to be a nice example: [enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqoop/sqoop_import.htm).
2. When creating a file with sqoop try the option --fields-terminated-by     which sets the field separator character. If you set it to something different then comma "," (e.g. semicolon ";" or something else not appearing in your data) and provide this information in your hive create statement (e.g. FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';') and leave out the serdeproperties it should work.